# Very weird Mongoose/MongoDB issue when running MEAN site on Openshift

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have uploaded a site to Openshift...I have had to make many changes...including learning about version-ing and nvm (Node Version Manager). I had to go through a lot of npm version stuff just to make the requests happen (namely, the server used express version 3.2.5, while I was using 4.2.0, locally). Anyway, now I am on this weird problem where the mongoose function - `Model.findById()` simply doesn't seem to be able to find an object that is clearly in the database by the `_id` attribute. The flow is like this (and you can see it for yourself here - http://hackabox-eamonbenproject.rhcloud.com - my project):

When I try to load a post on the page where you can view all the post info...the `GET` request happens, a route is called by express here:

```
app.get('/api/posts/:id', api.showinfo);
```

That `api.showinfo` function is this currently (although I have tried many different things):

```
exports.showinfo = function(req, res, next) {
  var postId = req.params.id;

  Post.findById(postId, function (err, post) {
    console.log("what did u find?" + post);
    res.send({ postinfo: post.postinfo });
    //res.json(post);
  });
};
```

That `console.log("what did u find?" + post)` outputs `null`, which means that something with mongoose's `findById` function is going wrong.

I have logged to make sure that `postId` is the correct id...so that isn't the problem. I have also tried changing `res.send({ postinfo: post.postinfo });` to `res.json(post)`, `res.send(post.postinfo)`, `res.send({ profile: post.postinfo })` - with no luck.

Does anyone know why `findById` might not be finding anything...the `post.postinfo` refers to my Mongoose virtual schema which looks like this:

```
PostSchema
  .virtual('postinfo')
    .get(function() {
      return {
        '_id': this._id,
        'posttitle': this.posttitle,
        'content': this.content,
        'username': this.username,
        'date': this.date
      };
    });
```

I thought using it with `res.send` how it is used in the user auth system in my seed might work - it is used there like this - and it works fine:

```
exports.show = function (req, res, next) {
  var userId = req.params.id;

  User.findById(userId, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return res.send(404);

    res.send({ profile: user.profile });
  });
};
```

For some reason when I use it with the `Post` model I made, it doesn't want to work on Openshift, I'm pretty sure it works locally.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After downgrading my MongoDB version locally to 2.4.6 (same as openshift server version) - the site started having the same problems locally that it does on the server...so it is definitely an environment issue - I'm guessing that some of the packages that depend on Mongo need their versions changed too - so I am going to try that and see if that helps. It seems to be a problem with conflicting versions within the seed when I run it locally now - here are all the mongo related npm packages from my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "hackabox",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {

    ...

    "mongoose": "~3.8.8",
    "connect-mongo": "mrzepinski/connect-mongo#2135988",

    ...
  },

  ...

}
```

Does anyone know what versions to use for MongoDB v2.4.6?

**UPDATE**

I tried Mongoose v3.5.0 and it doesn't work - I was looking at the commit dates and it seemed like around the time that MongoDB v2.4.6 was released. What other packages need to be updated/downgraded to sync with the openshift server?

**UPDATE**

Did a few things, with no luck - but ultimately I ended up ssh-ing into the openshift server and running:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

It responded with an `EACCES` error - but it also spat out all the version numbers anyway - so here they are:

```
glob error { [Error: EACCES, readdir '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man']
  errno: 3,
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/man' }
/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib
├── abbrev@1.0.4
├── ansi@0.2.1
├── ansicolors@0.3.2
├── ansistyles@0.1.3
├── archy@0.0.2
├── asn1@0.1.11
├── assert-plus@0.1.4
├── async@0.2.9
├── aws-sign@0.3.0
├── bignumber.js@1.1.1
├── block-stream@0.0.7
├── boom@0.4.2
├── bson@0.2.3
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── bytes@0.2.1
├── child-process-close@0.1.1
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── chownr@0.0.1
├── cmd-shim@1.1.0
├── colors@0.6.2
├── columnify@0.1.2
├── combined-stream@0.0.4
├── commander@1.1.1
├── config-chain@1.1.8
├── connect@2.7.10
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
├── couch-login@0.1.18
├── cryptiles@0.2.2
├── ctype@0.5.3
├── debug@0.7.2
├── delayed-stream@0.0.5
├── editor@0.0.5
├── express@3.2.5
├── forever-agent@0.5.0
├── form-data@0.1.1
├── formidable@1.0.14
├── fresh@0.2.0
├── fstream@0.1.25
├── fstream-ignore@0.0.7
├── fstream-npm@0.1.6
├── generic-pool@2.0.3
├── github-url-from-git@1.1.1
├── github-url-from-username-repo@0.0.2
├── glob@3.2.8
├── graceful-fs@2.0.0
├── hawk@1.0.0
├── hoek@0.9.1
├── http-signature@0.10.0
├── inherits@2.0.0
├── ini@1.1.0
├── init-package-json@0.0.14
├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
├── keypress@0.2.1
├── lockfile@0.4.2
├── lru-cache@2.5.0
├── methods@0.0.1
├── mime@1.2.11
├── minimatch@0.2.14
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── mongodb@1.3.19
├── mute-stream@0.0.4
├── mysql@2.0.0-alpha9
├── nan@0.4.4
├── node-gyp@0.12.2
├── node-static@0.6.9
├── node-uuid@1.4.1
├── nopt@2.1.2
├── normalize-package-data@0.2.8
├── npm@*
├── npm-registry-client@0.3.3
├── npm-user-validate@0.0.3
├── npmconf@0.1.12
├── npmlog@0.0.6
├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
├── once@1.3.0
├── opener@1.3.0
├── openshift-node-web-proxy@*
├── optimist@0.4.0
├── options@0.0.5
├── osenv@0.0.3
├── path-is-inside@1.0.0
├── pause@0.0.1
├── pg@0.12.3
├── promzard@0.2.0
├── proto-list@1.2.2
├── qs@0.6.5
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── read@1.0.5
├── read-installed@0.2.4
├── read-package-json@1.1.6
├── request@2.25.0
├── require-all@0.0.8
├── retry@0.6.0
├── rimraf@2.2.6
├── semver@2.1.0
├── send@0.1.4
├── sha@1.2.1
├── sigmund@1.0.0
├── slide@1.1.5
├── sntp@0.2.4
├── supervisor@0.5.2
├── tar@0.1.19
├── text-table@0.2.0
├── tinycolor@0.0.1
├── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
├── uid-number@0.0.3
├── which@1.0.5
├── wordwrap@0.0.2
└── ws@0.4.25
```

Do I really need to go about making all my global npm packages the same versions as the packages that are on openshift to insure that it works (for the ones that are relevant)?

I ran `npm list -g` locally - and this is what I get:

```
/usr/lib
├─┬ bower@1.3.3
│ ├── abbrev@1.0.5
│ ├── archy@0.0.2
│ ├─┬ bower-config@0.5.0
│ │ ├── mout@0.6.0
│ │ └─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│ │   ├── minimist@0.0.8
│ │   └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ ├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.1
│ ├─┬ bower-json@0.4.0
│ │ ├── deep-extend@0.2.8
│ │ └── intersect@0.0.3
│ ├── bower-logger@0.2.2
│ ├─┬ bower-registry-client@0.2.0
│ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ ├─┬ bower-config@0.4.5
│ │ │ ├── mout@0.6.0
│ │ │ └─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│ │ │   ├── minimist@0.0.8
│ │ │   └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ ├── lru-cache@2.3.1
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.27.0
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ │ └── request-replay@0.2.0
│ ├─┬ cardinal@0.4.4
│ │ ├── ansicolors@0.2.1
│ │ └─┬ redeyed@0.4.4
│ │   └── esprima@1.0.4
│ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
│ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
│ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
│ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
│ ├── chmodr@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ decompress-zip@0.0.6
│ │ ├─┬ binary@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── buffers@0.1.1
│ │ │ └─┬ chainsaw@0.1.0
│ │ │   └── traverse@0.3.9
│ │ ├── mkpath@0.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13-1
│ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│ │ └─┬ touch@0.0.2
│ │   └── nopt@1.0.10
│ ├─┬ fstream@0.1.25
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├─┬ fstream-ignore@0.0.7
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├─┬ glob@3.2.9
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│ ├─┬ handlebars@1.3.0
│ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.3.6
│ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.33
│ │     └── amdefine@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ inquirer@0.4.1
│ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ ├─┬ cli-color@0.2.3
│ │ │ ├── es5-ext@0.9.2
│ │ │ └─┬ memoizee@0.2.6
│ │ │   ├── event-emitter@0.2.2
│ │ │   └── next-tick@0.1.0
│ │ ├── lodash@2.4.1
│ │ ├── mute-stream@0.0.4
│ │ ├── readline2@0.1.0
│ │ └── through@2.3.4
│ ├─┬ insight@0.3.1
│ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ ├─┬ configstore@0.2.3
│ │ │ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.15
│ │ │ │ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
│ │ │ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
│ │ │ │ └── esprima@1.0.4
│ │ │ └── uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├─┬ lodash.debounce@2.4.1
│ │ │ ├── lodash.isfunction@2.4.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ lodash.isobject@2.4.1
│ │ │ │ └── lodash._objecttypes@2.4.1
│ │ │ └─┬ lodash.now@2.4.1
│ │ │   └── lodash._isnative@2.4.1
│ │ ├── object-assign@0.1.2
│ │ └─┬ request@2.27.0
│ │   ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
│ │   ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
│ │   ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │   ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │   │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │   │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │   ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │   │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │   │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │   │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │   │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │   ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │   │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │   │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │   │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │   ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │   ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │   ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │   ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │   ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │   └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ ├── is-root@0.1.0
│ ├── junk@0.3.0
│ ├── lockfile@0.4.2
│ ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│ ├── mout@0.9.1
│ ├── nopt@2.2.0
│ ├── opn@0.1.1
│ ├── osenv@0.0.3
│ ├─┬ p-throttler@0.0.1
│ │ └── q@0.9.7
│ ├─┬ promptly@0.2.0
│ │ └─┬ read@1.0.5
│ │   └── mute-stream@0.0.4
│ ├── q@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ request@2.34.0
│ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ ├─┬ request-progress@0.3.1
│ │ └── throttleit@0.0.2
│ ├── retry@0.6.0
│ ├── rimraf@2.2.6
│ ├── semver@2.2.1
│ ├─┬ shell-quote@1.4.1
│ │ ├── array-filter@0.0.1
│ │ ├── array-map@0.0.0
│ │ ├── array-reduce@0.0.0
│ │ └── jsonify@0.0.0
│ ├── stringify-object@0.2.0
│ ├─┬ tar@0.1.19
│ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
│ ├── tmp@0.0.23
│ ├─┬ update-notifier@0.1.8
│ │ ├─┬ configstore@0.2.3
│ │ │ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.15
│ │ │ │ │ ├── underscore@1.4.4
│ │ │ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3
│ │ │ │ └── esprima@1.0.4
│ │ │ ├── object-assign@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── uuid@1.4.1
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.27.0
│ │ │ ├── aws-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── cookie-jar@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.2.10
│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│ │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│ │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│ │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│ │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│ │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│ │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│ │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│ │ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│ │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│ │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│ │ └── semver@2.1.0
│ └── which@1.0.5
├─┬ express@3.2.5
│ ├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
│ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ ├─┬ connect@2.7.10
│ │ ├── bytes@0.2.0
│ │ ├── cookie@0.0.5
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.14
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ │ └── qs@0.6.5
│ ├── cookie@0.1.0
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ debug@1.0.4
│ │ └── ms@0.6.2
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0
│ ├── methods@0.0.1
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.4
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
│ └─┬ send@0.1.0
│   └── mime@1.2.6
├─┬ express-generator@4.2.0
│ ├─┬ commander@1.3.2
│ │ └── keypress@0.1.0
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.5
├─┬ generator-angular@0.8.0
│ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
│ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
│ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
│ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
│ ├─┬ wiredep@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@0.1.1
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── has-color@0.1.7
│ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
│ │ │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│ │ │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│ │ └── lodash@1.3.1
│ └─┬ yeoman-generator@0.16.0
│   ├── async@0.2.10
│   ├─┬ cheerio@0.13.1
│   │ ├─┬ CSSselect@0.4.1
│   │ │ ├── CSSwhat@0.4.7
│   │ │ └─┬ domutils@1.4.3
│   │ │   └── domelementtype@1.1.1
│   │ ├── entities@0.5.0
│   │ ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.4.0
│   │ │ ├── domelementtype@1.1.1
│   │ │ ├── domhandler@2.2.0
│   │ │ ├── domutils@1.3.0
│   │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13-1
│   │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│   │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│   │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│   │ └── underscore@1.5.2
│   ├── class-extend@0.1.1
│   ├── dargs@0.1.0
│   ├── debug@0.7.4
│   ├── diff@1.0.8
│   ├─┬ download@0.1.17
│   │ ├─┬ decompress@0.2.3
│   │ │ ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
│   │ │ ├─┬ extname@0.1.2
│   │ │ │ └── ext-list@0.1.0
│   │ │ ├── map-key@0.1.4
│   │ │ ├─┬ stream-combiner@0.0.4
│   │ │ │ └── duplexer@0.1.1
│   │ │ ├─┬ tar@0.1.19
│   │ │ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ fstream@0.1.25
│   │ │ │ │ └── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│   │ │ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ │ └─┬ tempfile@0.1.3
│   │ │   └── uuid@1.4.1
│   │ ├── each-async@0.1.3
│   │ ├── get-stdin@0.1.0
│   │ ├── get-urls@0.1.2
│   │ ├─┬ nopt@2.2.1
│   │ │ └── abbrev@1.0.5
│   │ ├─┬ request@2.36.0
│   │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│   │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│   │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│   │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│   │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│   │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│   │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│   │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│   │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│   │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│   │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│   │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│   │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│   │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│   │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│   │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│   │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│   │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│   │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│   │ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│   │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.0
│   │ └─┬ through2@0.4.2
│   │   ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
│   │   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│   │   │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │   │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│   │   │ └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│   │   └─┬ xtend@2.1.2
│   │     └── object-keys@0.4.0
│   ├─┬ file-utils@0.1.5
│   │ ├── isbinaryfile@0.1.9
│   │ ├── lodash@2.1.0
│   │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│   │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│   │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│   ├── findup-sync@0.1.3
│   ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
│   │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
│   │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│   │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│   ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
│   ├─┬ inquirer@0.4.1
│   │ ├─┬ cli-color@0.2.3
│   │ │ ├── es5-ext@0.9.2
│   │ │ └─┬ memoizee@0.2.6
│   │ │   ├── event-emitter@0.2.2
│   │ │   └── next-tick@0.1.0
│   │ ├── mute-stream@0.0.4
│   │ ├── readline2@0.1.0
│   │ └── through@2.3.4
│   ├── isbinaryfile@2.0.1
│   ├── lodash@2.4.1
│   ├── mime@1.2.11
│   ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
│   ├─┬ request@2.30.0
│   │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│   │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│   │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│   │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│   │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│   │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│   │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│   │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│   │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│   │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│   │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│   │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│   │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│   │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│   │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│   │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│   │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│   │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│   │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.9.15
│   │ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│   │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│   ├── rimraf@2.2.8
│   ├── shelljs@0.2.6
│   ├── text-table@0.2.0
│   └── underscore.string@2.3.3
├─┬ generator-angular-fullstack@1.4.2
│ ├─┬ chalk@0.4.0
│ │ ├── ansi-styles@1.0.0
│ │ ├── has-color@0.1.7
│ │ └── strip-ansi@0.1.1
│ ├─┬ wiredep@0.4.2
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@0.1.1
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@0.1.2
│ │ │ └── has-color@0.1.7
│ │ └── lodash@1.3.1
│ └─┬ yeoman-generator@0.16.0
│   ├── async@0.2.10
│   ├─┬ cheerio@0.13.1
│   │ ├─┬ CSSselect@0.4.1
│   │ │ ├── CSSwhat@0.4.5
│   │ │ └─┬ domutils@1.4.3
│   │ │   └── domelementtype@1.1.1
│   │ ├── entities@0.5.0
│   │ ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.4.0
│   │ │ ├── domelementtype@1.1.1
│   │ │ ├── domhandler@2.2.0
│   │ │ ├── domutils@1.3.0
│   │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.13-1
│   │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│   │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│   │ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│   │ └── underscore@1.5.2
│   ├── class-extend@0.1.1
│   ├── dargs@0.1.0
│   ├── debug@0.7.4
│   ├── diff@1.0.8
│   ├─┬ download@0.1.16
│   │ ├─┬ decompress@0.2.3
│   │ │ ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
│   │ │ ├─┬ extname@0.1.2
│   │ │ │ └── ext-list@0.1.0
│   │ │ ├─┬ map-key@0.1.1
│   │ │ │ └── mout@0.9.1
│   │ │ ├─┬ stream-combiner@0.0.4
│   │ │ │ └── duplexer@0.1.1
│   │ │ ├─┬ tar@0.1.19
│   │ │ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.7
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ fstream@0.1.25
│   │ │ │ │ └── graceful-fs@2.0.3
│   │ │ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ │ └─┬ tempfile@0.1.3
│   │ │   └── uuid@1.4.1
│   │ ├── each-async@0.1.2
│   │ ├── get-stdin@0.1.0
│   │ ├── get-urls@0.1.1
│   │ ├─┬ nopt@2.2.0
│   │ │ └── abbrev@1.0.5
│   │ ├─┬ request@2.34.0
│   │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.5.0
│   │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2
│   │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.2
│   │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.4
│   │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5
│   │ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.0.0
│   │ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2
│   │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2
│   │ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1
│   │ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4
│   │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.0
│   │ │ │ ├── asn1@0.1.11
│   │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.1.2
│   │ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.2
│   │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.0
│   │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│   │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.3.0
│   │ │ ├── qs@0.6.6
│   │ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1
│   │ │ │ └── punycode@1.2.4
│   │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.3.0
│   │ └─┬ through2@0.4.1
│   │   ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
│   │   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1
│   │   │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │   │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│   │   │ └── string_decoder@0.10.25-1
│   │   └─┬ xtend@2.1.2
│   │     └── object-keys@0.4.0
│   ├─┬ file-utils@0.1.5
│   │ ├── isbinaryfile@0.1.9
│   │ ├── lodash@2.1.0
│   │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│   │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│   │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│   ├── findup-sync@0.1.3
│   ├─┬ glob@3.2.9
│   │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│   │ └─┬ minimatch@0.2.14
│   │   ├── lru-cache@2.5.0
│   │   └── sigmund@1.0.0
│   ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
│   ├─┬ inquirer@0.4.1
│   │ ├─┬ cli-color@0.2.3
│   │ │ ├── es5-ext@0.9.2
│   │ │ └─┬ memoizee@0.2.6
│   │ │   ├── event-emitter@0.2.2
│   │ │   └── next-tick@0.1.0
│   │ ├── mute-stream@0.0.4
│   │ ├── readline2@0.1.0
│   │ └── through@2.3.4
│   ├── isbinaryfile@2.0.1
│   ├── lodash@2.4.1
│   ├── mime@1.2.11
│   ├── mkdirp@0.3.5

...
```

Can't actually post it all - this question has gotten very long, haha.

So I guess I could go through and make sure all of them are the same...but does anyone know which ones would be most important for the problem I am having?

Jeepers, that would be annoying!

Comment: @Pogrindis Hey dude...got a real stumper here...i got really far with learning what u taught me about versions...the requests happen now...but I can get past why this is happening now...its a doozy...hoping you have run into the same thing.

Comment: I realized my mongo versions are off too - that could be messing with stuff...fixing that now - hoping that is the issue.

Comment: I've never used openshift, but shouldn't it be using the version of modules that you specify in your package.json file? Also, instead of just writing out the post results in findById, also write out the err. There might be useful information there.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple thanks for your response...the `err` is null - i tried that already...I am going to make sure all the versions are correct...as of right now I have only really payed attention to express and node versions - I am downgrading my mongo locally to match with the openshift version - and I hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple i think it is still a version problem...read my latest update in the question...I think it gets to the root of the problem.

Comment: @Pogrindis i think it is still a version problem...read my latest update in the question...I think it gets to the root of the problem.

Comment: Those are the global packages. Doesn't openshift allow you to specify local dependencies from your package.json file? It's something that every other PaaS provider allows, so if they don't you should probably find a different provider.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple yah - i could do that - so u are saying that the problem only lies in the local package versions somewhere?

Comment: @TimothyStrimple one of the things i tried locally to make it work was i replaced all the versions in my package.json file with `"*"` except for express and node which I specified for because they need to be specific versions to work with openshift...I was hoping that npm would sort out the dependencies...but it still is having the same problem...if that is kind of what u were talking about...

Comment: @TimothyStrimple to reiterate - and i think this is to your point that it is a local problem...the same thing is happening locally on my computer...that is happening on openshift...after i made my local node and express global npms the same version as openshift.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple the environments should be the same now...and they are both experiencing the same symptoms so i think they are.

Comment: My point was it shouldn't matter what version of express you're using. Openshift should download the version you specify. If it's not doing that and it's limited to a specific version, you should find a new host.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple after much tinkering - i think i resolved the problem - the only reason i am using openshift is because it is free (the only node hosting i could find that was free with a mongo database) - if u know any others let me know...ill post my answer...but its been an error minefield.

Comment: Azure Websites, Heroku, Nodejitsu, etc. There are plenty of free options. Combine that with a MongoLab or MongoHQ database and you've got free node hosting and database.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple didnt realize there was free mongo hosting separate - never thought about breaking it up like that - +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on getting my site to work on openshift for a few days now. I spent the last day or two making sure that all of the npm package versions that I use on my computer are the same as the versions that are used on openshift. After I synced up all the versions, it was a lot of work to re-factor my code, but I eventually got it working.

The major error I had to figure out was that when I was trying to do a `PUT` request, even thought I wasn't changing the `_id` field - it would give me this error:

```
MongoError: Mod on _id not allowed
```

I eventually realized that I needed to create an object with all the same info, just without the `_id` field to get the update to work.

Other than that, it just took a lot of tinkering to get it right - here is the result of my labor - http://hackabox-eamonbenproject.rhcloud.com/ - the problem I have been having pertains to the forum I was making, so check that out - it is fully functional.